# Apply pipe to input box

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular2-pipe

I have written `thousandsSeparatorPipe` and it is working fine with the `label` as shown below.

```
  <ion-label fixed>{{project.contingency | thousandsSeparatorPipe}}</ion-label>
```

But how can I apply that `pipe` to the `ion-input`? Because I need to show the thousands separator when user types on the below `numeric` box.Any help, please?

```
<ion-input type="number" formControlName="budget" [(ngModel)]="project.budget" ></ion-input>
```

Comment: You can write a custom directive to format the input value. Here: https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, It's **not possible** to use **pipes** over inputs like above, even in AngularJS which is not a recommended way too.

Inorder to use you need to  apply the two-way data binding with two instructions. `[ngModel]="project.budget| thousandsSeparatorPipe" (ngModelChange)="project.budget= $event"`

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/2mzlxqa3B1toHCHoHgeN?p=preview)**

Alternatively you could use some of the **[`mask`](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask)** libraries for input out there and create a directive.

Comment: Should have been a comment.

Comment: @Faisal I am expanding still.

Comment: My actual code is like this.How can I apply above to it? `<ion-input type="number" formControlName="budget" [(ngModel)]="project.budget" (ngModelChange)="calculateContingency()"></ion-input>`

Comment: i have posted above <ion-input type="number" formControlName="budget" [(ngModel)]="project.budget | thousandsSeparatorPipe"(ngModelChange)=""project.budget= $event";calculateContingency()"></ion-input>

Comment: It says `unexpected closing tag`. Hope problem is here `(ngModelChange)=""project.budget= $event";calculateContingency()"`.Any clue?

Comment: you have two quotes, remove one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154063/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-sampath).

Comment: Thank you so much for the support.I'll use mask directive :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to handle this method with above implementation? Because it (i.e. `this.project.budget`) converts into a `string` with `separator` no. `this.project.contingency = (this.project.budget * this.project.contingencyPercentage) * 1 / 100;`. This is not working due to string. Any clue?

Comment: convert the string to integer and then  calculate contigency

Comment: I did that. But it's having weird behavior after detect changes method. please see this image: https://i.imgur.com/QJ1ZMKY.png Any clue how to do this?